# How can I require reindexing in magento backend

Tags: magento, indexing

I made a custom module and I want the user to be prompted to reindex a certain index table. How can I show this prompt progmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the status of the indexing process by using this code

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');

$process->changeStatus(Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX);
```

Alternatively, we can do it all at once

```
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')
->getProcessById(1)
->changeStatus(Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX);
```